# Literature around NP vs EXPTIME

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes

Even if it isn't a crucial point, I don't see any literature around this question. Are there relativisation results ?

Wouldn't it be quite straightforward to prove strict inclusion by adapting non-deterministic time hierarchy theorem by exploring all possible paths of the NP machine ?

Comment: It's easy to prove an oracle separation between NP and EXP. There is a non-deterministic time hierarchy theorem which tells us that NP is strictly contained in NEXP. I don't see how it could be adapted to NP vs EXP.

Comment: @Robin Yes, of course, an oracle such that $NP^A \neq PSPACE^A$ implies that $NP^A \neq EXP^A$. But as I don't find oracle such that $NP^B = EXP^B$, then if there isn't, a proof of $NP \neq EXP$ could be relativizing.

Comment: The Complexity Zoo (http://qwiki.stanford.edu/index.php/Complexity_Zoo) says:
... There exist oracles relative to which $EXP = NP = ZPP$ [Hel84a], [Hel84b], [Kur85], [Hel86],.... See for example *Two oracles that force a big crunch* (http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~fortnow/papers/nexp.ps)

Comment: @Vor, @Robin, I think these should be answers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Complexity Zoo](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:E#exp) says:

... There exist oracles relative to which $EXP=NP=ZPP$ [Hel84a], [Hel84b], [Kur85], [Hel86],....

See for example [Two oracles that force a big crunch](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~fortnow/papers/nexp.ps).

Perhaps the original oracle used by Dekhtyar is *less powerful* (and simpler): *On the relativization of deterministic and nondeterministic complexity classes* in *Proc. Mathematical Foundations of CS* 1977 ... but I don't have his paper.

Comment: Thank you. The exact name of Dekhtyar paper is On the relativization of deterministic and nondeterministic complexity classes.